# Attributes for functions with currying

Tags: functional-style, attributes

Is there a way to set attributes for a function which holds for all arguments when currying?

When evaluating, e.g.,

```
SetAttributes[ x, NHoldAll ]
N[ x[1], 10 ]
N[ x[1][1],10 ]
```

I get

```
x[1]
x[1][1.000000000]
```

and I'm looking for some way to get

```
x[1]
x[1][1]
```

instead.

The first argument of `SetAttributes` should be a symbol so evaluating `SetAttributes[x[i_]]` or `SetAttributes[x[1]]` doesn't work.
None of the documentation on attributes and functions related to currying gives any indication of how to do this.

Comment: The attribute HoldAll only covers x[..]. If you give an additional argument, this is evaluated by N. To achieve your aim, you must define a second function.

Comment: The thing is that in my case the x[1][j] represent variables in the first step of a method which solves subsets of equations, substitutes solutions, solves new subsets etc. The i'th step introduces new variables x[i][j] (j = 1, ... ). I can't just define x[ a, b ] as a second function since x[i] is passed as a symbol name of a variable...

Comment: But you can define a new function, e.g.: g[j_]=x[1][j] or even g[i_,j_]= x[i][j] and give g the Attribute: HoldAll.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, it does. Thanks :)